# QGIS how to export slope data with x, y

Tags: qgis, dem, coordinates, slope

I have a shapefile with contour line data, that looks like the following:

[image]

Columns 1, 2, 4, and 5 are geometric data and column 3 is contour data. (MultiLineString type)

First, I tried 'TNI interpolation' with 5 pixel property. So, I made a 5m DEM. (raster type)

Second, I tried 'Slope' tool, so I got slope data. (raster type)

Finally, I'm using 'Polygonize' tool. So, I made slope data. (vector type)

I want to get slope data corresponding to the coordinate value(x, y)...
What should I do? It's been less than two weeks since I started QIGS, so I'm looking for it in various ways, but it's not working.

Comment: What do you exactly want? The slope at specifics coords?

Comment: Can you explain what is wrong with the raster slope data from the Slope tool? By definition, raster data is (x,y) data. So you probably need to explain your requirements in more detail.

Comment: Hi, @fsg! sorry to late. What i want to get slope data with the x,y !

Comment: Hi, @TomBrennan! the slope tool works! I want to match slope to x,y coord.

Comment: You'll need to be more specific. As per my previous comment, Slope data is raster data, which is by definition (x,y) data. You should edit your question with more details of the data and the exact outcome you need, in order for someone to be able to answer.

Comment: @TomBrennan Thanks advice! I'll post in detail soon. Thanks!